# node mon app crashed waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: stack, mern

I was running in port 8000
I have changed the port, and run the cmd as administrator but it's still not working
what should I do
my dot env code is here

```
  PORT = 8000,
  NODE_ENV = 'development',
  DB_USERNAME ""
  DB_PASSWOD=""
  SESS_NAME = 'sid',
  SESSION_SEET= "",
  SESS_LIFETIME =86400000,
```

this is part of index.js

```
require( "dotenv" ).config()

const ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
const {
  PORT = 8001,
  NODE_ENV = 'development',
  SESS_NAME = 'sid',
  SESSION_SECRET,
  SESS_LIFETIME = ONE_DAY,
} = process.env

const IN_PROD = NODE_ENV === 'production'
```

Comment: What does "still not working" mean? What does "crash" mean in this case? Does it produce an error message? Have you checked the log files? Why does this have the "stack" and "mem" tags? All we know about your application is what you tell us, and you haven't told us enough to make more than a wild guess at what the problem might be. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and the linked articles, then modify your question accordingly.